# Row and column position after itemChanged signal on QTablewidget

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

HI,

I want to get the changed datas row and column position after the signal

void QTableWidget::itemChanged ( QTableWidgetItem * item )

please help

Comment: Did you even try to look at the documentation for QTableWidgetItem before asking the question?  It's not as if the row and column functions are part of a hidden API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple,

item->[row()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtablewidgetitem.html#row) and item->[column()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtablewidgetitem.html#column)